# Unable to get flutter_pdfview to display a PDF

Tags: flutter, pdf

I am trying to get a screen to display a PDF that is stored in the assets folder of my app - I have done this before and never had this issue so am completely confused and am sure i must just be missing something simple.

The console output reads like it cannot find the file but its there and the asset is listed in the pubspec.yaml.

On the app itself it appears to just load a while screen (shown below)

here is my main.dart...

```
class MyPdfViewer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String pdfPath = 'assets/test.pdf';
  //MyPdfViewer({required this.pdfPath});
  MyPdfViewer();
  @override
  _MyPdfViewerState createState() => _MyPdfViewerState();
}
class _MyPdfViewerState extends State<MyPdfViewer> {
  late PDFViewController pdfViewController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My PDF Document"),
      ),
      body:
      PDFView(
        filePath: widget.pdfPath,
        autoSpacing: true,
        enableSwipe: true,
        pageSnap: true,
        swipeHorizontal: true,
        onError: (error) {
          print(error);
        },
        onPageError: (page, error) {
          print('$page: ${error.toString()}');
        },
        onViewCreated: (PDFViewController vc) {
          pdfViewController = vc;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And my pubspec.yaml...

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.2.5

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/rose.pdf
    - assets/test.pdf
```

And the error console output...

```
D/com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore( 7034): Starting PdfiumAndroid 1.9.2
I/PlatformViewsController( 7034): Hosting view in view hierarchy for platform view: 1
E/FrameEvents( 7034): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents( 7034): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/flutter ( 7034): java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/FrameEvents( 7034): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
```

[image]

I have tried different PDFs incase there is an error with the file, but that makes no difference.

I was getting the same issue in the app i am working on so i have created a completely clean app with nothing but this file and still getting the same error.

Comment: you can do this way 

fromAsset('path to asset folder, 'filename.pdf').then((f) {
     
        widget.pdfPath = f.path;
     
    });